# How to handle additional directories in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a zip file named agent-20.1.80.8366.zip, when I extract this zip it is giving additional directory inside the parent dir like below:

agent-20.1.80.8366/agent-20.1.80.8366/**files**

I would like to extract and move files from child directory to it's parent directory and remove that empty child directory and then I want to pass that path as a variable.

Please someone help with bash snippet that should strictly validate and proceed, and then parent path should be stored in a variable

expected output to be:

agent-20.1.80.8366/**files**

Comment: You forgot to write, which command you used to unzip the archieve. Perhaps you need something like `unzip -j agent-20.1.80.8366.zip`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "validate"? Also, are you saying you want the procedure to work for an arbitrary number of child directories? Do you know how to write loops in bash?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ mv agent-20.1.80.8366/agent-20.1.80.8366/files agent-20.1.80.8366/files
$ rmdir agent-20.1.80.8366/agent-20.1.80.8366
```

This will fail if `agent-20.1.80.8366/agent-20.1.80.8366` is not empty, which imo is a good thing, since you are assuming that it will empty if `files` is moved.

Comment: This is not gonna help to validate and move, because if there is 2 additional directories created instead of 1 additional dir.

Comment: @CSR : In your question, you mentioned that you only want to move one single directory after unzipping, which means that you want to have the other ones left intact. If this is not the case, please explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Using find to first move the file up one level

```
find agent-20.1.80.8366/agent-20.1.80.8366 -type f -execdir  mv -f '{}' .. \;
```

Then using find to remove the remaining directory

```
find agent-20.1.80.8366 -type d -name "agent-20.1.80.8366" -delete
```

Comment: find agent-20.1.80.8366/agent-20.1.80.8366 -type f -execdir  mv -f '{}' .. \;    This is moving only files, but not sub directories

Comment: Yeah. This is what I read as outlined in the original post.